# Sound reflections plot

Tags: sound, multipath

I have sound files that contain recordings of an impulse signal in a room.

I'd like to make such a plot from it. I basically want to compare early reflections.

How do I go about it? Is just taking the waveform, pulling the absolute values and plotting it in bar/impulse form the right way? Or is this just an idealized form? If this is all wrong, could anyone point me towards the correct way of comparing early reflections in a plot form?

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an idealized case of the echogram that simply depicts the times of arrival and energy of reflections. You can see this type of plot in literature and as an output in modelling software such as CATT-A and ODEON.

If you have a real-life impulse response then you can obtain information about reflections by representing the IR in logarithmic scale, i.e.:

[image]